# First representation theorem for sesquilinear forms - what is the role of the "core"?

Tags: functional-analysis, mathematical-physics, spectral-theory

In the **[first representation theorem](https://books.google.cz/books?id=k-7nCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA322&lpg=PA322&dq=first%20representation%20theorem%20core&source=bl&ots=w5JIscgczK&sig=U6AE1UNlsPTYVhKpXtqDZfi9QAg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8yqQVeaVFsXzUOiehoAI&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=first%20representation%20theorem%20core&f=false)**, the notion of the core of a sesquilinear form appears. What is the intuition behind this notion, in context of this theorem and in general? I appreciate any comments and answers!

([Here are some relevant definitions and background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sefio.png). All excerpts are from Kato's *Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators*, pp.308-322.)

> [image]

Comment: @Zev Chonoles Thanks for the nice edit!

Comment: No problem :) ${}$

Comment: Just to clarify: Do you know the concept of a core for a closed operator? *(Not quite the same.)*

Comment: @Freeze_S Not really, could you give me some reference, please?

Comment: @wondering Try reading Weidmann, Lineare Operatoren. *(Best for closed operators!)*

Comment: @wondering: Try also Reed & Simon, Self-Adjointness. *(Good for closed forms.)*

Comment: You have seen Kato's pag.166 where the core of a closed operator is defined?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of *core* is given in the same Kato's book that you cited at page 317 for a closed sectorial form and at page 166 for a closed operator.

I refer to this last (but the first is a particular case).

> If $T: X \rightarrow Y$ is a closed operator and $\mathbf{D}(T)$ its domain, than a
>   subspace $\mathbf{D}$ of $\mathbf{D}(T)$ is a *core* of $T$ if the set
>   $\mathbf{G}=\{ (u,Tu) : u \in \mathbf{D} \}$ is such its closure is
>   the graph $\mathbf{G}(T)$ of $T$.

Note that the closure of $\mathbf{G}$ is in the induced topology on $X\times Y$.

As an intuition i think that we can see a core $\mathbf{D}$ as a subspace of the domain of $T$ such that if we take a restriction of the operator $T$ to this subspace we can reconstruct its graph by the values on $\mathbf{D}$ taking limits of convergent sequences $(u_n,Tu_n)$ for $u_n \in \mathbf{D}$.